# Binding to a property with Cocoa Bindings that is only available in a subclass

Tags: swift, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

Coming from WPF the following issue was always an easy task:

- I have a class called baseClass that has two subclasses called
  subClassA and subClassB.
- My View Controller has an array called
  objects of type [baseClass] and property called selectedObject of
  type baseClass.
- Due to the fact that subClassA and B derive from
  baseClass, I can put instances of both types into the array objects and into the selectedObject property.

Now I'm going to make an UI for editing these classes. It consists of the following:

- An NSPopupButton that uses an NSArrayController to fetch the objects array.
- A text box that edits a property called name, declared in baseClass.
- A text box that edits a property called nickName, declard in subClassB.

I've already achieved to display the contents of the objects array within the popup button and binding the selection to selectedObject of the ViewController. Also, I inserted a text field and wired up everything so that the name property is working (self.ViewController.selectedObject.name).

But how do I bind the second text field to the nickName property without crashing? Since nickName is only available on subClassB, what has to be done to make the binding get only evaluated when a subClassB instance is "selected"? Should this be toggled via the hidden/enabled bindings?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Create a category/extension, for the purposes of your UI, of `baseClass`. In this extension, define two computed properties (untested, typed in browser):

```
extension baseClass {
    var hasNickName: Bool { return (self as? subClassB) != nil }
    var editableNickName: String? {
        get { return (self as? subClassB)?.nickName }
        set(newName) { (self as? subClassB)?.nickName = newName }
        }
}
```

You can bind the enabled/visible property of views to `hasNickName` and bind any value to `editableNickName`, which will be functional for objects of `subClassB` but a useless property for `baseClass` objects.

Comment: Footnote: if you have other code that sets `nickName` you'll need some KVO magic to make sure `editableNickName` gets the necessary property change notifications.

Comment: Is this really the only solution? This looks very messy for such a simple problem... I mean, your approach using an extension is nice, but the fact that Cocoa does not solve this problem for you is very disappointing when comparing it to WPF bindings.

Comment: @barnacleboy you could also see if setting the `NSRaisesForNotApplicableKeysBindingOption` binding option to `false` would be sufficient.